# Latex - How do I make subscripts smaller when they are in fractions

Tags: size, latex, fractions

[image]

I want the '2' subscript to be proportionally smaller in the second alpha (the one in the fraction). As you can see, the alphas themselves are smaller, so their subscripts should be too. How should I accomplish this?

I am already using a newcommand in place of the default subscript command in order to make subscripts as small as possible:

```
\newcommand{\s}[2]{#1_{\scriptscriptstyle\rm #2}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using something I found elsewhere and adapting it to use with Greek letters. It might help in your case

```
\left(C_2-a_2\right)^{\alpha^{}_{2}}
```

Apparently inserting that empty superindex forces latex to measure the height of the letter, and pushes the subindex down a little. I'm not entirely sure why. Maybe someone else can comment on the details

Answer (score 1):

The command `scaleto` from package [`scalerel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scalerel) seems to fit here. To make subscripts of (three) different sizes:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\[
\alpha_2 = \alpha_2^{{\left(\alpha_{\scaleto{2}{2.5pt}}-1\right)} {\frac{1}{\alpha_{\scaleto{2}{2pt}}-1}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i solved it "nesting" the pedix:

```
x_{_{2}}
```